# Where to find latest map navigation firmware versions for VW?

Tags: vw, passat, navigation

I have a 2012 Volkswagen Passat SEL. 
I believe that the installed navigation is RNS-810.

Where can I find information on all the available revisions, when they were released, what was updated on each firmware, etc?

Which company controls this information? VW? Or a 3rd party?

Comment: Do you really want an answer? I do know that the Volvo forum is replete with excellent info and so is the forum for the make of car I drive...

Comment: I honestly do want an answer. But these old and outdated car forums are filled with spam. Also, I have searched there. But not the information I am seeking is more detailed than a specific set of someone's firmware.

Comment: a simple google search for rns-810 will give you hundresds of hits about the software and how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Local dealership should be able to do a map update if that is what you're looking for.

Head unit also has versions and revision listed in the information section

Comment: looking at the dealership is a no brainer if I want to get ripped off and wait 6 hours for a mundane update like map update.

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul I was quoted $20 CAD for a map update. I think it's just a new SD card with data